Can ${\rm cond}([A,B])$ be controlled by ${\rm cond}(A)$ and ${\rm cond}(B)$?
For a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, the condition number of $A$ is defined by ${\rm cond}(A) := \|A\|_2\|A^\dagger\|_2$, where $A^\dagger$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$.
Now consider the following block matrix $[A, B]$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$.
A proof is given that when $A$ and $B$ have row full rank equal to $n$, ${\rm cond}([A,B]) \leq {\rm cond}(A) + {\rm cond}(B)$ in Condition number of a block matrix.
My question is whether there is a similar conclusion when both matrices $A$ and $B$ are full column rank. In other words, when both matrices $A$ and $B$ are full column rank, can ${\rm cond}([A,B])$  be controlled by ${\rm cond}(A)$ and ${\rm cond}(B)$?

The answer is no. Consider $A=B=\pmatrix{1\ 1}$ for instance. Here $A$ and $B$ have finite condition numbers but $[A,B]$ is singular.
